# Replace #include <> with #include ""

Tags: c++, c, grep, include

I'm new to grep, and during a refactoring process over C and C++ files I encontered with the problem of replacing system includes `#include <>` with local includes `#include ""`.

**Is there a way to do that using grep with any replacement tool, say for any C or C++ file on a given directory and subdirectories?**

Comment: No, `grep` is just a [pattern matching search tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). It cannot replace content.

Comment: Should be possible with sed instead.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I know, what I mean is using grep to match the include patterns and then do the replace using grep output.

Comment: Your best bet is search and replace with a regex, but event then it's not ideal. It would be safer to search and replace each header individually, rather than using a regex.

Comment: The tool you are looking for is sed not grep. The manuals should give you enough clarity to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `sed`:

```
cat file.cpp | sed -re 's/#include\s*<([^>]+)>/#include "\1"/g' > fixed_file.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in perl:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/<(.*)>/\"\1\"/g" abc.h
```

Or maybe safer as:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/#include <(.*)>/#include \"\1\"/g" abc.h
```